# hql one to many/many to one selection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm fairly new to Hibernate and MySQL databases.  I'm having a problem retrieving the releases of a system from my database. When trying ***"select s from System s left join fetch s.releases"*** I get the following error: **org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet**.

Within the root cause section of the server error it says: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release releases1_ on system0_.id=releases1_.system_id' at line 1**

I'm trying to figure out what the HQL query for retrieving a list of systems along with it's corresponding releases would be. I've looked at quite a few examples on here, but the result has been the same.

My entities are as follows:

**System.java**

```
package com.wayne.edu.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "system")
public class System {

    @Id @GeneratedValue private long id;
    private String name;
    private String issueTrackerUrl;
    private String programmingLang;
    private String versionControlUrl;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "system", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Release> releases;
    /**********************************************************************/
    Getters and Setters
```

**Releases.java**

```
package com.wayne.edu.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "release")
public class Release {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "system_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private System system;

    /**********************************************************************/
    Getters and Setters
```

**SystemDAO.java**

```
package com.wayne.edu.entities;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
public class SystemDAO {

    @Autowired private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /**
     * @Transactional annotation below will trigger Spring Hibernate transaction manager to automatically create
     * a hibernate session. See src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml
     */
    @Transactional
    public List<System> findAll() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List systems = session.createQuery("from System").list();
        return systems;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<System> findAllWithReleases() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List systems = session.createQuery("select s from System s left join fetch s.releases").list();
        return systems;
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
package com.wayne.edu;


import com.wayne.edu.entities.*;
import com.wayne.edu.entities.System;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.List;


/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/edu")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    public SystemDAO systemDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hibernate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model model) {
        List<System> systems = systemDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("systems", systems);

        List<System> systemsWithReleases = systemDAO.findAllWithReleases();
        model.addAttribute("systemsWithReleases", systemsWithReleases);
        return "hibernate";
    }
  .
  .
  .
```

MYSQL Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `release` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `system_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `system_id_idx` (`system_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `system_id` FOREIGN KEY (`system_id`) REFERENCES `system` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `system` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `issueTrackerUrl` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `programmingLang` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `versionControlUrl` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue, apparently the word "release" has a predefined meaning within MySQL that I was unaware of so it was causing my queries to have errors when I tried to retrieve the release of a particular system.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the system using
    **select s from System s**
and get the releases by using system.getReleases() method.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow your suggestion.  Shouldn't I generate the list of releases for the System s using the HQL query?

Comment: @RaymondLemon Hibernate will do it for you. All you have to do is to fetch the system object. Then if you just invoke the getReleases() method, hibernate will execute the required query in backend and fetch the releases.

Comment: would this be done within my controller or SystemDAO class? I tried a for loop with "systems.get(i).getReleases();" inside however, that only works properly in the controller.

Comment: It should work in DAO as well. Could you explain what is not working.

Comment: It says that getReleases is an unresolved method within the DAO. Here are screenshots: http://imageshack.com/a/img96/3306/mlbq.png  and http://imageshack.com/a/img440/3661/uix4.png

Comment: @RaymondLemon This is because the object is not typecasted to a System. One way of handling this is to do a ((System)Systems.get(i)).getReleases()